# How do I get an XML-attribute to display in an WPF ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, .net-4.0

I've got a simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <languages default="en">
    <language code="en" name="English" />
    <language code="de" name="Deutsch" />
    <language code="es" name="Espanol" />
    <language code="fr" name="Français" />
</languages>
```

whose `language` nodes I've declared as the `ItemsSource` for a ComboBox in C#:

```
userLanguageComboBox.ItemsSource = languagesXml.Descendants("language");
```

The ComboBox displays is defined as such in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="userLanguageComboxBox" DisplayMemberPath="@name" />
```

The problem is, that the ComboBox generates four empty entries, it doesn't seem to find the attribute (If I leave out the `DisplayMemberPath` property, the four `language` nodes show up as text):

[image: Screenshot of the Combobox]

How can I fix this?

(I'm using .NET 4.0.)

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? LINQ to XML would be a good candidate here if you're on .Net 3.5 or above?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness He is indeed using Linq to XML as `Descendants` is a method on `XContainer`.

Comment: Thanks MikeEast. So a small change to your query should solve the problem - languagesXml.Elements("language").Attributes("name") select n;

Comment: I'm not that familiar with WPF, but it seems like the framework *should* be able to evaluate the `XElement` and get the attribute using `@name`. The point is that you shouldn't have to break down the data source yourself. But I'm only guessing here.

Comment: I've updated the question with the .Net version. And yes, I'm using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML you can get all the name attributes using:

```
var names = from n in XElement.Load("xml.xml").Elements("language").Attributes("name") select n.Value;
```

Bind this to the ComboBox

```
userLanguageComboBox.ItemsSource = names;
```

Comment: Thank, that was almost it. I had to do the select on `n.Value` and remove the `DisplayMemberPath` to make it work.